# How to stop scraping when no more table to pull?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

How can I stop my for loop from going to the next page when the current page no longer has any pandas table to pull?

Right now i have it coded to go through a certain pageRange + 1 but does not know when there is no more pages to parse.

Thanks!

```py
# set variables for url to pull from
wmsLoggedIn = "https://enterurlhere/solution/entitylist.htm?" #root logged in page
pageSize = 300 # how many results per page
pageNo = 0 # starting page; starts at 0
entityName = "Shipment" # entity of the view
currentView = 51339 # view id to pull data from
pageRange = 2 # total pages returned on wms view

savefilesin = "G:\\webscraper\\Scraped Files\\"

# set variables for filename function
now = datetime.now()
randomstring = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters
                + string.digits) for n in range(6)])

def generate_filename():
    return str(entityName) + "-" + str(now.strftime("%m%d%Y-%H%M%S")) + "-" + str(randomstring) + ".csv"

modified_dfs = []
for pageNo in range(pageRange + int(1)):
    urlSpecifics = "entityName={entityName}&pageNo={pageNo}&pageSize={pageSize}&currentViewId={currentView}".format(entityName=entityName, pageNo=pageNo, pageSize=pageSize, currentView=currentView)
    # open entity page
    driver.get(wmsLoggedIn+urlSpecifics)
    html = driver.page_source
    for df in pd.read_html(html, attrs={"class":"roundedTable"}, header=5):
        df.dropna(how="all", axis="columns", inplace=True)
        df.drop({"No"}, axis="columns", inplace=True)
        df.dropna(how='all', axis=0, inplace=True)
        modified_dfs.append(df)
    pd.concat(modified_dfs).to_csv(savefilesin + generate_filename(), index=False)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time # capture total time it took for the process to run
print("Process Success and saved the file as: " + generate_filename() + " It took " + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time)) + " to process!")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Stop the iteration when `pd.read_html` returns a None object?

Comment: would that be handled through an if statement? can you please show me how to implement that in my code?

Comment: Something like `tables = pd.read_html(html, attrs={"class":"roundedTable"}, header=5) if tables is None.. `. You could use a `break` statement to exit the loop, which I don't particularly like. Even better refactor your code into a function and return when 'tables` is None. Also it would help if you provided an example of the site you're trying to scrape. There might be other ways to stop the iterations. Such as looking for a next page button on the page or any other element that will tell you that you reached the last page.